# Android SdkManager --list doesn't open

Tags: android, command-line

When I run the command `sdkmanager.bat --list` It shows the following error :

[image]

My `android-sdk` folder contains folder `cmdline-tools` which contains `tools` which has `bin` and `lib` folders and `source.properties` file.
I have windows 10 and I sat `ANDROID_HOME` Variable to the `tools` folder and the path is set to `bin` folder.

Last Notices:- When I run `sdkmanager.bat --help`, It works. I have only that `tools` folder and I need to install the rest. I have only the `sdk` and not `android studio`.